# how to exclude a task based on the output of a command

Tags: gitlab-ci

In gitlab-ci.yml, I am using the `rules:if` command to define when a step is performed and when not.

I would to skip a step based on the output of a command.
To be a bit more precise, the command is filtering the content of a file.

For example:

```
variables:
  MY_VAR: "$(some command here)"

deploy_to_s3:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - some command here
  rules:
    - if: '$MY_VAR == "upload"'
```

Unfortunately, that does not work. You cannot use `$()` in variables defined that way. I know I could instead run the step always and simply skip the script commands like this:

```
deploy_to_s3:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - export MY_VAR=$(some command here)
  script:
    - if [[ $MY_VAR == "upload" ]]; then
    - some command here
    - fi
```

But then the step would always be visible.

Is there another way around that?